# How to stay RESTful with a complex API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7

I need to implement an API that is essentially a GET but depending on a date, could involve DELETE and POST actions as well. Let me explain, for a particular day, the API needs to add 10 items to one table randomly selected from another table but this is only done once a day. If the items added are from the previous day, then the API needs to delete those items and randomly add 10 new ones. If multiple calls are made to the API in the same day, then it's just a GET after the initial creation. Hope this makes some sense.

How would I implement this as a RESTful API if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
GET /Items
```

If the next day has arrived, then generate 10 new items before returning them.  If the next day has not arrived, then return the same 10 items you previously returned.  There is no reason the server cannot update the items based on a GET.  The client is not requesting an update so the request is still considered safe.

Comment: Agreed, there doesn't seem to be any reason for a client to see this request as anything other than a GET. There's no need to reveal the implementation the server happens to use to generate this set of data as part of the abstraction exposed to the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but just by looking at this, all I can think is the following: What a horrible thing, to perform an add which depending on what it's added, performs a delete. No disrespect, but seriously. Or maybe it is the way you are describing it.

Whatever the case, if you want to have a RESTful API, then you have to treat GET and PUT distinctively.

I don't think you have a clear use-case picture of how your API (or your system for that matter is to be done.) My suggestion would be to re-model this as follows:

Define a URI for your resource, say /random-items

- a `GET /random-items` gets you between 0 and 10 items currently in the system.
- a `PUT/random-items` with an empty body does the following:

  - delete any random items added on or before yesterday
  - add as many random items as necessary to complete 10
- an invocation to `DELETE /random-items`) should return a `405 Method Not Allowed` http error code.
- an invocation to `POST`/random-items` should add no more than 10 items, deleting as needed.
- `/random-items/x` is a valid URI so long as x is one of the items currently under /random-items.

  - A `GET` to it should return a representation for it or a 404 if it does not exist
  - A `DELETE` to it deletes it from under `/random-items` or 404 if it does not exist
  - A `PUT` to it should change its value if it makes sense (or return a `405`)
  - A `POST` to it should return a `405` always

That should give you a skeleton sorta RESTful API.

However, if you insist, or need to overload GET so that it performs the additions and deletions behinds the scene, then you are making it non-RESTful.

That in itself is not a bad thing if  you legitimately have a need for it (as no architectural paradigm is universally applicable.) But you need to understand what RESTful mean and when/why/how to break it.

Comment: Yeah, I know it sounds horrible, hence why I'm trying to figure out how best to deal with this. I do understand REST and what you suggests is RESTful-ish as you mentioned. Perhaps this is a case when I break REST principle because the complex logic is entirely on the backend without the need for the front-end to make those separate calls which is my dilemma to begin with. All the API cares about is give me the 10 items for today but the logic calls for those 10 items to change on a daily basis. I suppose I could implement a daily CRON job in the backend to populate and change the 10 items.

Comment: Nah, simply overload the GET and PUT as mentioned here (with DELETE and POST returning a 405), and with the PUT doing the deletions and updates (both requiring date arithmetic logic) behind the scenes. A cron job then can access/update the resource with `curl -T`.